# JWT token validation has failed

Tags: kentico, kentico-13

trying to upgrade my K13 site but I'm getting the following error:

JWT token validation has failed. Make sure you have set the same 'CMSHashStringSalt' app setting for all application instances.

I updated both MVC and CMS with the correct CMSHashStringSalt on the config files.

Answer (score 0):

If the upgrade finished successfully - the Upgrade Start and Finish events are logged in the Event log without any errors between them, then make sure:

- you are using HTTPS and valid SSL certificates for both admin and presentation URL
- the admin app's site is not nested underneath the front end app's site in the IIS - they need to run side-by-side as separate IIS web sites or separate virtual apps
- apply the latest hotfix to exclude already known and fixed bugs
- check whether you are using any custom authentication logic with some third party NuGet packages like Microsoft.Identity.Web or System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt - newer versions could break the JWT token encryption in Kentico.